# Can you write to the sdcard folder when there is no sdcard?

Tags: android, sd-card

So I'm testing an app on a galaxy s3 on 4.1 and an older phone that runs 2.3. Neither phone has an sdcard in it but when I use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` on my galaxy s3 it directs me to a folder called sdcard0 within a folder called storage. When I run it on the older phone it gives me the path mnt/sdcard/ and the sdcard folder is read only.

I am trying to create a folder in these directories. I can do it on my s3 but not on my older phone.

Is there something similar to the storage folder I'm missing on the older phone or can I write to the sdcard folder when there is no sd card present?

EDIT: I have the external write permissions in my manifest

Comment: Just a hunch but did you try without getAbsolutePath()?

Comment: When an sdcard is inserted the system will mount it to that mount point.  Without an sdcard it is just a mount point pointing to nothing.  So, no you can't write to it.

Comment: What does getExternalStorageState() say?

Comment: Pretty sure that the S3s sdcard0 is its internal storage. Confusing naming, but I think that's the case!

Comment: can you give more details, code samples and results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On some phones, as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29) suggests, the word *external* is not to be taken all too serious:

> Note: **don't be confused by the word "external" here.** This
>   directory can better be thought as media/shared storage. **It is a
>   filesystem that can hold a relatively large amount of data** and that
>   is shared across all applications (does not enforce permissions).
>   **Traditionally this is an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage** in a device that is distinct from the protected
>   internal storage and can be mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

You can check if the storage is *really* external or not, using the [`Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#isExternalStorageRemovable%28%29). If it's not removable, you should always be able to write to it (given that you have the permissions declared).

If it *is* however removable, you'll need to check it's current state with [`Environment.getExternalStorageState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29). Here's a quick example of how to use it:

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write!
} else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
    // Mounted read only...
} else {
    // Something is wrong...
}
```

So in these cases, you can write to the external storage.

---

**Important**: As the documentation specifies at multiple points, the above methods work for the ***primary*** external storage. Some devices (like the Motorola Xoom) have both an internal "external" storage, and an SD-Card.

There seems to be no "generalized" way to access the "*secondary* external storage" on such devices, although there is a [standard](http://source.android.com/tech/storage/) now, introduced with Android 4.2

> Devices may contain multiple instances of external storage, but
>   **currently only the primary external storage is exposed to developers through API.**
>
> [...]
>
> Starting in Android 4.2, devices can support multiple users, and
>   **external storage must meet the following constraints**:
>
> - [...]
> - **Secondary external storage must not be writable by apps.**

It seems to depend on the vendor which storage (internal or *real* external) is considered the primary one. Not much you can do here (without things getting messy...)

---

If there is no external storage present, you can use your applications [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal), or the caching directory, depending on what kind of data you're storing.